# I then tried to ask additional permission from the user "manage_pages" but I still get Require extended permission: manage_pages

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have tried to do a FB like from my android app

where the user must sign in with FB.

But I got this error in FB response:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 283, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#283) Require extended permission: manage_pages}, isFromCache:false}
```

Why is "manage_pages" permission needed anyway? 
I'm an Admin of page in which the post exist.

I then tried to ask additional permission from the user "manage_pages"

but I still get the same error.

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (permissions.size() > 0 && !permissions.contains("publish_actions")) {
            requestPublishPermissions(this, session,
                    Arrays.asList("publish_actions", "manage_pages"),
                    PublicMacros.REQUEST_CODE_PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS);
        }

    public static void requestPublishPermissions(Activity activity,
            Session session, List<String> permissions, int requestCode) {
        if (session != null) {
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest reauthRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                    activity, permissions).setRequestCode(requestCode);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(reauthRequest);
        }
    }
```

This is the code that does FB like:

```
Request request = new Request(
                            session,
                            takeFromPublicMacrosOrServer(currentOffer.fbPostId)
                                    + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST,
                            new Request.Callback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                    // Request complete
                                    if (response.getError() == null) {
                                        UnlockRequestToServer unlockRequestToServer = new UnlockRequestToServer(
                                                mOffersListActivity,
                                                PublicMacros.TYPE_UNLOCK_FB_LIKE,
                                                currentOffer.fbPostId);

                                        // (4) unlock 4 - skip
                                        sendUnlockRequestToServer(
                                                unlockRequestToServer,
                                                currentLockView);
                                    } else {
                                        final String errorMsg = "error: "
                                                + response.getError()
                                                        .toString();
                                        Log.e(MyLogger.TAG, errorMsg);
                                        if (BaseApplication
                                                .getCurrentActivity() != null) {
                                            BaseApplication
                                                    .getCurrentActivity()
                                                    .runOnUiThread(
                                                            new Runnable() {
                                                                public void run() {
                                                                    if (PublicMacros.DEBUG) {
                                                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                                                BaseApplication
                                                                                        .getCurrentActivity(),
                                                                                errorMsg,
                                                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                                                .show();
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                    String re = response.toString();
                                }
                            });
                    request.executeAsync();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Graph API v2.0 or higher, your app needs to be review if you use extended permissions like `manage_pages` to be able to use this with other users than app admins or developers.

I suspect that this is your problem.

Have a look at my answer here: [Facebook me/feed can only post on developers account only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420126/facebook-me-feed-can-only-post-on-developers-account-only/25420238#25420238)

Comment: I'll read your link. But even before that: why is "manage_pages" permission needed anyway? I'm an Admin of page in which the post exist.

Comment: You don't describe in detail what you want to do. What is meant by "do a FB like"? A Page like, an URL like, an object like? You can't like Pages via the Graph API, so that's a dead end anyway. And for the other types of likes, the `user_likes` permission is enough.

Comment: I try to do a like to a FB post in a FB page. Sorry for not being clear. I thought it is mentioned in `I'm an Admin of page in which the post exist.`

Comment: so why does this error might thrown from FB? under what condition. I didn't try to modify a FB page. Just do "FB like" to a post in it.

Comment: You don't show the code where you try to like to post. That doesn't make much sense. To like a post doesn't require the `manage_pages` permission, so it's unlikely that the error arises from the code you posted.

Comment: I guess you can identify the code line where the error occurs, right? So, where?

Comment: there is no exception thrown. The error is in FB server and returns as the json result `public void onCompleted(Response response) {`