# Facebook me/feed can only post on developers account only

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am encountering a strange situation here.While posting to facebook I want my app to bypass the dialog the asks to write something and show my own customize dialog.For that reason I have to use "me/feed".The app works fine when I post something in the developers account.But when I try to post in some other account it sometime returns nothing or sometime returns:

```
08-21 12:26:29.332: D/Facebook-Util(6796): POST URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
08-21 12:26:29.722: D/Tests(6796): got response: {"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

I am really confused about what mistake I am doing here.Why the message is not posting other than the developers account..?

This is my relevant code:

```
if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                            facebook.authorize(BoonDriveActivity.this,
                                    new String[] { "publish_stream","publish_actions","manage_pages","status_update"},//This are the permissions
                                    new DialogListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancel() {
                                            // Function to handle cancel event
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                            // Function to handle complete event
                                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                                            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                                            editor.commit();
                                            LayoutInflater inflater=BoonDriveActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                                            View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.createsharedialoglinkedin,null);
                                            final AlertDialog d1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(BoonDriveActivity.this)
                                            // Your other options here ...
                                            .setView(layout)
                                            .create();//My custom dialog
                                            d1.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
                                            d1.show();
                                            lntxtfilename=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.txtfilename);
                                            lnetmessage=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.et_message);
                                            ln_btn_share=(Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
                                            ln_btn_showlink=(Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_showlink);
                                            lnshowlink=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.et_showlink);
                                            ln_btn_share.setText("SHARE ON FACEBOOK");
                                            ln_btn_showlink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                    ln_btn_showlink.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                    lnshowlink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                    lnshowlink.setText(finallink);
                                                }
                                            });
                                            lntxtfilename.setText("Share"+" "+filename+" "+"with:");

                                            ln_btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                    //String s = ((GlobalFilename)BoonDriveActivity.this.getApplication()).getGlobalState();
                                                    if(lnetmessage.length()==0)
                                                    {
                                                        Toast.makeText(BoonDriveActivity.this,"Please enter message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    }
                                                    else{
                                                    String share1 = lnetmessage.getText().toString();
                                                    //String finalmsg=share1+"\n"+s;
                                                    System.out.println("This is the final msg linkedin--->"+ finallink);
                                                    //lnetmessage.setText(finalmsg);
                                                    //postToWall();
                                                    postToWall(share1,finallink);
                                                     d1.dismiss();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });



                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                                            // Function to handle error

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                                            // Function to handle Facebook errors

                                        }

                                    });
                        }



                    }
```

I searched a lot about this,but couldn't find a solution.Please help.

I am using the following method to post to wall:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void postToWall(String message,String link){

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

                parameters.putString("message", message+link);
               // parameters.putString("link",link);
               /* parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
                parameters.putString("picture", link);*/
                try {
                     String response = facebook.request("me");
                    facebook.request("me");
             response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") ||
                    response.equals("false")) {
                showToast("Blank response.");
            }
            else {
                showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I was in hurry so couldnt indent it properly

Comment: I suspect many here will be in a hurry NOT to scroll code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app hasn't been reviewed yet, no other users than the admins and developers of this app are able to give to appropriate permissions.

This is described in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review

Quote:

> If you're the developer of an app and are the only person using it, then your app doesn't need to go through review. Since you're the developer, all app capabilities should be available. You will still need to take your app out of developer mode, but you should be able to do that without going through review.

And, BTW, there is no `status_update` permission...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.so when and how can i review my app??

Comment: RTFM... I'd expect that you read the docs that I linked first, before posting another question.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.I will try it.BDW do you know how long it will take to review the app??

Comment: Good. So what did you fix?

Comment: I have enabled the "public_action" permission

Comment: You mean `publish_actions`... You'll still need to let FB review your app if if needs to be publically used.

Comment: yeah sorry it is publish_actions.Actually first I was developing the app in my developer account.Then after seeing this post I used my clients developers account.There I saw that the relevant permission is already activated(as this is an application of an web-site built with rest api).I just replaced the app id in my app and pasted necessary hash keys in client`s developer account and it was all set.Thanks for your info.Saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is possible that you grant permission after you accept them in Facebook.Firstly delete app permission from you're account in Facebook ant try it one more time.