# facebook SDK for PHP couldn't log in with other account

Tags: php, facebook

I have an application use this to log in.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
));
```

I have test on my facebook account, it works fine and facebook pop up the message

**My App will receive the following info: your public profile...**

The problem is when I try to use different account to log in, it return nothing.

anyone know where is the problem?

url shows
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
client_id=499519323487644&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2FfbLogin%2Fexamples%2Fexample.php&state=fe56e342043378a4afb4593d9c13372e&
sdk=php-sdk-3.2.3&scope=email%2C+user_birthday

page display nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the `user_birthday` permission, your app needs to be reviewed by Facebook to be able to request this from non-admin/developer/tester users.

Have a look at my answer here: [Facebook me/feed can only post on developers account only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420126/facebook-me-feed-can-only-post-on-developers-account-only/25420238#25420238)

In you case, there should be some kind of error message normally. check your console output.

Comment: i do using uer_birthday, i have check my console output, notthing is there, How to get reviewed by FB?