# Android facebook feed posting error

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to post on facebook from my android app. It is working fine using previously created app id.

Some thread is saying it is because of publish_actions.

But using new on it is giving following error.

```
Response: {"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

My posting code is below:

```
public void shareVideoInFacebook() {

        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        byte[] data = null;
//      shareAdvertisement();
        String link = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
        String dataMsg = "Share for DateClip";
        Bundle param;
        facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        System.out.println("Access Token: " + pref.getFbAccessToken());
        facebook.setAccessToken(pref.getFbAccessToken());
        facebook.setAccessExpires(pref.getFbAccessExpire());
        AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            // is = new FileInputStream(dataPath);
            // data = readBytes(is);
            param = new Bundle();
            param.putString("message", dataMsg);
            param.putString("filename", "DateClip");
            // param.putByteArray("video", data);
            param.putString("name", "DateClip");
            param.putString("caption",
                    "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
            param.putString("description", "Watch the Video");
            param.putString("link", link);
            // param.putString("picture",
            // "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");
            mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", param, "POST",
                    new RequestListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onMalformedURLException(
                                MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            System.out.println("IO Exception.........");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFileNotFoundException(
                                FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            // "File not found...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            System.out.println("FileNotfound.........");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e,
                                Object state) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            // "Error...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            System.out.println("Error.........");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            // "Sharing Completed...",
                            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            System.out
                                    .println("Successfully Sent.......................................................");
                            System.out.println("Response: " + response);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    // UI code goes here
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Successfully shared on Facebook.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                                  shareForPassionPoint();
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    }, null);
            // mAsyncRunner.request(dataPath, parameters, httpMethod, new F,
            // state);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420126/facebook-me-feed-can-only-post-on-developers-account-only

Answer (score 0):

This was the case with out iOS app. It may be the same for Android also.

"
Please get your app reviewed again.

Recently, all the permissions except 3 basic ones (email, public_profile and user_friends) have been removed from the app if you had it reviewed by an older version of the Graph API.

Follow the steps as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review
"

Hope this helps :)