# share picure to timeline using sdk for android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

im using the android facebook sdk to integrate facebook into my app. Im trying to share pics to the users wall. When I login to my app and share a picture it also shares to my facebook timeline. When someone else logs in and tries to share a pic to their timeline it doesnt work. Why is this? Is there some setting i need to change.

Comment: is your account is the developer account??

Comment: @kgandroid- yes, it is the dev account

Comment: I faced the same problem and found the solution


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420126/facebook-me-feed-can-only-post-on-developers-account-only

Comment: @sararoberts Have you solved this ?